# Oracle SQL - Column Ambiguously Defined

Tags: sql, oracle

implementing this query - error of "column ambiguously defined" being thrown. I know it is RE column names and the instances of them being duplicated. Cannot determine which is causing the error.

```
 SELECT case.case_id,
   case.client_id,
   case.description,
   case.date_filed,
   case.date_closed,
   solicitor.solicitor_id,
   solicitor.first_name,
   solicitor.surname,
   SUM(note.time_spent) total_time_spent
FROM note, case
INNER JOIN note
ON note.case_id = case.case_id
INNER JOIN solicitor
ON solicitor.solicitor_id = note.solicitor_id
GROUP BY note.case_id,
     note.solicitor_id,
     case.client_id,
     case.description,
     case.date_filed,
     case.date_closed
ORDER BY note.case_id,
     case.date_filed;
```

Comment: *"I know it is RE column names and the instances of them being duplicated. "* - I don't understand what you mean by that.

Comment: Can you show the complete error?

Comment: Your query looks like it's meant to confuse. You join `note` on `case` using old join notation, and then join `note` again using a "new" (1992+) inner join, but still not aliasing it. So I think that might be your error. But apart from that, `case` is a keyword, and having a table with this name, which is again not aliased, makes the query even harder to read.

Comment: @Atri ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined
00918. 00000 -  "column ambiguously defined"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 23 Column: 10

Answer (score 2):

`note` is in the `from` clause twice.  A simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `from` clause.  Then, the `GROUP BY` clause should have all non-aggregaed columns in the `FROM` clause.

Also, table aliases would make the query easier to write and to read:

```
SELECT c.case_id, c.client_id, c.description, c.date_filed, c.date_closed,
       s.solicitor_id, s.first_name, s.surname,
       SUM(n.time_spent)as  total_time_spent
FROM case c INNER JOIN
     note n
     ON n.case_id = c.case_id INNER JOIN
     solicitor s
     ON s.solicitor_id = n.solicitor_id
GROUP BY c.case_id, c.client_id, c.description, c.date_filed, c.date_closed,
         s.solicitor_id, s.first_name, s.surname,
ORDER BY c.case_id, c.date_filed;
```

And, `case` is a bad name for a table because it is a SQL keyword.  It is not an Oracle reserved word, but it still looks awkward.

Answer (score 1):

I looks like the actual error lies in the fact that you use the `note` table twice, without aliasing it.

Answer (score 0):

execute the query

```
SELECT case.case_id,
   case.client_id,
   case.description,
   case.date_filed,
   case.date_closed,
   solicitor.solicitor_id,
   solicitor.first_name,
   solicitor.surname,
   SUM(note.time_spent) total_time_spent
FROM note, case
INNER JOIN note
ON note.case_id = case.case_id
INNER JOIN solicitor
ON solicitor.solicitor_id = note.solicitor_id
GROUP BY case.case_id,
   case.client_id,
   case.description,
   case.date_filed,
   case.date_closed,
   solicitor.solicitor_id,
   solicitor.first_name,
   solicitor.surname
ORDER BY note.case_id,
     case.date_filed;
```

I have modified the columns of group by clause.